# Python looping through an array that can be of len 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, types

I have a dict, sometimes keys that i go through have arrays in them, through which i iterate by

```
item for item in dict[another_key]:
   ....
```

However sometimes there is no array but a single string, and then python throws “TypeError: string indices must be integers”

is there is a way to explicitly state that i want to work with arrays only, even if there is only one item in it?

Comment: That isn't valid syntax. It's a mixture of a `for` loop and a list comprehension, but is also neither at the same time.

Comment: Well you could check if the length of the element is greater than 1 first. 
Please provide a minimally working example if you would like to get further help.

Comment: @Ibragile Checking for the length would be useless, as strings also have a length that can be greater than 1. The OP should check `if isinstance(dct[another_key], list)`

Answer (score 1):

You can check if any variable is a dict via `if type(x) is dict`.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    some_dict = {"1": {"4" : 6}, "2": "test"}

    for key in some_dict: 
        if type(some_dict[key]) is dict: 
            print(f"value of key '{key}' is a dict: {some_dict[key]}")
        else: 
            print(f"value of key '{key}' is not a dict: {some_dict[key]}")
```

Output:

```
value of key '1' is a dict: {'4': 6}
value of key '2' is not a dict: test
```

In that way you can easily distinguish between dictionary values and other values like strings.

Comment: K thanks, i thought that there may be a magic keyword or something, but it doesnt look like so